# Derived class with differing interface

Tags: python, inheritance, adapter

The following code:

```
class Cache:

    def __init__(self):
        self._cache = []

    def store(self, data):
        self._cache.append(data)

    def stats(self):
        print('We are caching {} elements'.format(len(self._cache)))


class LegoCache(Cache):

    def store(self, weight, color):
        Cache.store(self, (weight, color))
```

has a problem in that the `store` method does not implement the interface of the base class.

How can this code be improved? I have the following ideas:

- do not derive from `Cache`, just make use of it.
- rename the `store` method in the base class to `store_base`

Are there other alternatives?

### EDIT

The base class must also support this other use case:

```
class ZombieCache(Cache):

    def store(self, dead_since, humans_eaten, can_be_saved=False):
        Cache.store(self, dict(
            dead_since=dead_since, 
            humans_eaten=humans_eaten, 
            can_be_saved=can_be_saved))
```

Comment: Does it really matter?

Comment: @StephenRauch, `PyCharm` isn't happy, so I am not happy. But seriously, isn't this a code smell?

Comment: I am a BIG pycharm, but what is the scope here?  Alternative to requiring the  caller to store to pass the tuple explicitly: `store((weight, color))`, or change the base store to `store(*args)`, then args is always tuple.

Comment: @StephenRauch, none of those appeal to me, since the whole point of the derived class is to offer a simplified interface to the caller, to adapt one interface to the other.

Comment: Fair enough....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a variable argument list in the base class:

```
class Cache:

    def __init__(self):
        self._cache = []

    def store(self, *args):
        self._cache.append(args)

    def stats(self):
        print('We are caching {} elements'.format(len(self._cache)))

class LegoCache(Cache):
    pass
    # "overloading" store isn't needed
```

So it isn't needed to overload this method or add methods with different names for specials cases:

```
cache = Cache()
legoCache = LegoCache()

cache.store(x)
legoCache.store(x, y)
```

Another solution may be delegation:

```
class LegoCache(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = Cache()

    def store(self, weight, color):
        self.cache.store((weight, color))
        # or just self.cache.store(weight, color) if you use the *args implementation
```

Comment: Nononono, the base class has a well defined implementation: it accepts a single data argument, which can be anything. The derived class provides a more convenient interface for a specific case.

Comment: @dangonfast: Indeed, this is not so nice. (Un-)fortunately, Python doesn't support _overloading_ of methods. If you doesn't like this, you must declare special methods for each item type. But note that you may call `store()` in a `LegoCache`as well. But then you should consider to use delegation instead of inheritance.

Comment: @dangonfast: I've added a delegation example.

Comment: Thanks! This seems the cleanest solution to me. Unfortunately the implementation hides a bit the fact that this is derived from `Cache`, but as you mentioned, without method overloading it is not possible to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it like this,

```
class Cache:

  def __init__(self):
      self._cache = []

  def store(self, data):
      self._cache.append(data)

  def stats(self): 
      print('We are caching {} elements'.format(len(self._cache)))


class LegoData(object):

  def __init__(self, weight, color):
      self.weight = weight
      self.color = color

class LegoCache(Cache):
   pass
```

Client will access it like this,

```
lego_cache = LegoCache()
lego_cache.store(LegoData(weight=10, color='Green'))
```

Comment: The whole point of the `LegoCache` is to provide a simple, usable interface so that its users have an easy time. This implementation simply provides a barebone `Cache`, and the user is fully responsible of instantiating the data. The `LegoCache` is therefore superfluous. On the other hand, the `LegoData` could indeed be used as data elements for the cache, but that is an (ortogonal) implementation detail, and not the subject of my question.